# Asymptotic notation and Growth of Combinations of Functions: Difference

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I need to prove or disprove the following conjecture:

if f(n) = O(h(n)) AND g(n) = O(k(n)) then (f − g)(n) = O(h(n) − k(n))

I am aware of the sum and product theorems for growth combination, but I could not find a way to apply them here, even though I know that subtraction can be rewritten as addition. Everywhere I looked defined the mentioned theorems, but lacked examples of subtraction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement is not true, consider the following counter-example:

Take `f(n) = 2n2 = O(n2)` and `g(n) = n2 = O(n2)`. We have:

`(f-g)(n) = n2`, which is definitely not a constant and hence `(f-g)(n) ≠ O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a more.. umm.. rigorous way to prove that? something that might be similar to the sum theorem?

Comment: That's pretty rigorous to me.  He gave you a counter example.  That's all you need to show that it's not true.

Comment: @GilDekel Maybe to clarify what thang said: theorems are true statements, often of the kind "if A, then B", and rigorous proof of that usually requires effort. In math, to disprove a claim of the sort "if A, then B", it suffices to give one case that satisfies A, but not B.